# Using % in languages without curly braces

Tags: cursor-movement

In C and C-like languages, I can use `%` to jump to the corresponding curly brace that the cursor is on. This is a well-known "trick".

But in Ruby for example:

```
def fun
    [1, 2].each do |n|
    end
end
```

This doesn't work, since ruby doesn't use the characters in `matchpairs` (set to `(:),{:},[:],<:>` by default.

I tried setting that, but it doesn't work:

```
:set matchpairs=def:end
E474: Invalid argument: matchpairs=def:end
```

Can I get this to work with languages such as Ruby as well? Note this is *not* a Ruby-specific question, other examples might be shell scripts (`if`/`fi`) or Lua (`function`/`end`), and many many more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [matchit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) plugin. This is included in modern vim distributions, so all you have to do to use it is add the following to your vimrc:

```
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

You can also get it packaged as a plugin if you prefer. It recognizes many keywords by default (including `def` and `end`) and can be extended to recognize more.

Comment: Note: typing `:runtime macros/matchit.vim` doesn't work; you need to put in in your vimrc and restart Vim...

Comment: I did that. Still doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

The following doc matchit, the the additions below in  ~/.vimrc worked for me

```
:runtime macros/matchit.vim
filetype plugin on
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is basically the same answer as the existing, accepted answer. The difference is your `filetype` command: it might be helpful if you described in detail why you've added this line and how it helps answer the question. (You've also got a couple of typos: "doc", "the the".)