# How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?

Tags: cursor-movement, delimiter-matching, filetype-xml, filetype-html

How to jump between matching tags (such as `<div>`, `<span>`, etc.) when editing HTML/XHTML/XML documents similarly as <kbd>%</kbd> is used to jump between matching parentheses?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using % in languages without curly braces](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/using-in-languages-without-curly-braces) ... This solution also works for HTML (just tested it, if you're on a `>` it will work like before, if you're on the `div` it will work like you want).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker If this question would be duplicated of general-like answer (using one plugin), then it won't allow for any answers which are dealing with html tags specifically.

Comment: However, the other question has exactly the same answer, so this is a duplicate.

Comment: Posted sample answer which won't fit into other question, so it's not duplicate then.

Comment: @Doorknob The fact that two questions happen to have the same answer does not necessarily mean that the questions are duplicates of each other.

Comment: Same question, same answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Vim ships with a macro called matchit that does this for you; all you need to do is activate it with `runtime macros/matchit.vim` in your vimrc. This will enable you to jump from, eg, a `<div>` to its `</div>`. Note that your cursor will have to be inside the angle brackets; if you're on the angle brackets, <kbd>%</kbd> will jump from one bracket to the other as normal.

Comment: I had to `set filetype=html` for my php file.  
Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281459/matchit-not-working#comment17704428_7283030

Answer (score 47):

You can jump between tags using visual operators, for example:

1. Place the cursor on the tag.
2. Enter visual mode by pressing <kbd>v</kbd>.
3. Select the outer tag block by pressing <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for inner tag block.

Your cursor should jump forward to the matching closing html/xml tag. To jump backwards from closing tag, press <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> to jump to opposite tag.

Now you can either exit visual by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, change it by <kbd>c</kbd> or copy by <kbd>y</kbd>.

---

To record that action into register, press <kbd>qq</kbd> to start recording, perform tag jump as above (including <kbd>Esc</kbd>), press <kbd>q</kbd> to finish. Then to invoke jump, press <kbd>@q</kbd>.

---

See more help at `:help visual-operators` or `:help v_it`:

> <kbd>at</kbd>      a `<tag> </tag>` block (with tags)
>
> <kbd>it</kbd>      inner `<tag> </tag>` block

---

Alternatively use plugin such as [matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) or [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

---

See also:

- [Using % in languages without curly braces](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/using-in-languages-without-curly-braces)
- [Jump to matching XML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [How can I find the close html tag quickly in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116362/how-can-i-find-the-close-html-tag-quickly-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [Navigating HTML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270396/navigating-html-tags-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [How to navigate between begin and end html tag?](https://superuser.com/questions/189815/vim-how-to-navigate-between-begin-and-end-html-tag) at superuser SE
- [VIM jump from one xml tag to the closing one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38187/vim-jump-from-one-xml-tag-to-the-closing-one) at Unix SE
- [How can I select an html tag's content in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/182355/how-can-i-select-an-html-tags-content-in-vim) at superuser SE

Answer (score 4):

The `xmledit` (http://vimawesome.com/plugin/xmledit) plugin allows to jump between open and close tags using

- <localleader><kbd>%</kbd>

Often <localleader> will be <kbd>\</kbd>, so you can jump with

- <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>

*NOTE:* Unlike `matchit`, you don't have to put your cursor inside the tag. Placing it right on the `<` or `>` is perfectly fine for the `xmledit` plugin. :)

*NOTE 2:* A drawback here is, that you can't use it in the visual mode. But this isn't a big deal, since you can always select the entire tag with <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively new and popular plugin [vim-matchup](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup) provides quite extensive support as long as there is syntax highlighting for the language, HTML included.