# cmake movement plugin

Tags: cursor-movement

I'm wondering, if there's a way to move with `%` in  CMakeLists.txt files between `foreach` and `endforeach`, `if` and `endif`, `function` and `endfunction`, …

googeling I only found plugins that allow calling cmake from within vim, but not for editing `CMakeLists.txt` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using either the plugin matchit (distributed with vim, just use `packadd! matchit`) or [match-up](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup) (external plugin).  The latter provides enhanced text objects and also enables highlighting of the words.

To define the matches for cmake, create a file `.vim/after/ftplugin/cmake.vim` containing:

```
if exists('loaded_matchit')
    let b:match_words = '\<if\>:\<elseif\>\|\<else\>:\<endif\>'
      \ . ',\<foreach\>\|\<while\>:\<break\>:\<endforeach\>\|\<endwhile\>'
      \ . ',\<macro\>:\<endmacro\>'
      \ . ',\<function\>:\<endfunction\>'
    let b:match_ignorecase = 1

    let b:undo_ftplugin .= "| unlet b:match_words"
endif
```

This should work with either plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find an existing solution, but the way to implement that doesn't seem too hard. One needs the matchit plugin (cf https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/784/6044)

```
" in .vimrc
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

And can then define `b:match_words` e.g. in [`.vim/ftplugin/cmake.vim`](https://github.com/pseyfert/vim/commit/e2cab48637c3a04a502724e26c80d6b602c17a55)

```
if exists("loaded_matchit")
  let b:match_words =  '^[^#]*\<if\>\s*(:^[^#]*\<else\>\s*(:^[^#]*\<elseif\>\s*(:^[^#]*\<endif\>\s*(\c'
  let b:match_words .= ',^[^#]*\<function\>\s*(:^[^#]*\<endfunction\>\s*(\c'
  let b:match_words .= ',^[^#]*\<foreach\>\s*(:^[^#]*\<endforeach\>\s*(\c'
  let b:match_words .= ',^[^#]*\<macro\>\s*(:^[^#]*\<endmacro\>\s*(\c'
  let b:match_words .= ',^[^#]*\<while\>\s*(:^[^#]*\<endwhile\>\s*(\c'
endif
```

to be honest I bodged this quickly and didn't go through the entire [matchit documentation](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/doc/matchit.txt), but so far it seems to do the job.

Comment: I added an answer which is a bit more up to date and includes an alternative plugn.  Note you should not need `^[^#]*` because comments are already excluded (I'm also not totally sure if you need the `\s*(`).  You can use `b:match_ignorecase` instead of `\c`.  `packadd! matchit` is the new style of enabling matchit.